# Class member is a derived object whose type is not yet known

Tags: c++, c++11

I am relatively new to C++ and I am in the process of creating a hypothetical 'Flight Management' application as a learning experience and to test out various new skills. Simply put, I have a `FlightPlan` class which among other things contains a private member pointer to an object of type `Aircraft` (well, for now).

Objects derived from `Aircraft` are pre-existing at the time of `FlightPlan` creation, and I want to be able to assign an `Aircraft` derived object pointer to a `FlightPlan` (the a/c that will carry out the flight in the plan) after a `FlightPlan` is constructed and not just during construction. 
(using a method such as

```
flight-plan-obj.AssignAircaft(cargo-aircraft-obj-pointer);
```

My issue is that `Aircraft` is an abstract class that `CargoAircraft` and `PassengerAircraft` derive from, therefore it is not known what 'type' of aircaft will be assigned to the flight plan during it's construction. My code is below. (Much has been left out for brevity)

```
class FlightPlan {
    private:
    string departure;
    string destination;

    Aircraft* aircraft; // The a/c that will later be assigned to the flight
                       // Obviously this is currently wrong

    public:
    FlightPlan(string dep, string dest);
    void AssignAircraft(Aircraft* ac);

    // Other methods
}
```

The `Aircraft` abstract class:

```
class Aircraft {
    protected:
    Aircaft(string tailId, string acType); // ctor for the sub-classes

    string tailId;
    string acType;

    public:
    virtual string Overview() const =0; // pure virtual method 
}
```

And an example of an object derived from `Aircraft`:

```
class CargoAircraft : public Aircraft {
    private:
    int cargoCapacity;

    public:
    CargoAircraft(string tailId, string acType, int cargoCapcity);
    string Overview() const override;

}
    // ctor defined in the .cpp file as:
    CargoAircraft::CargoAircraft(string tailId, string acType, int cargoCapacity)
    : Aircraft(tailId,acType), cargoCapacity(cargoCapacity) {};
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? My understanding was that pointer polymorphism would allow me to do:

```
Aircraft* aircraft; or Aircaft* aircraft = nullptr;
```

in `FlightPlan` and that would later accept an object pointer of a class derived from `Aircraft`?
On compile I receive: *error: ‘Aircraft’ does not name a type*

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach here? Do I need to give up on `Aircraft` being abstract and just treat it as more of a base class and give it a public default constructor and make it's methods just virtual instead of pure-virtual?

Any and all advice will be graciously received, and I will gratefully accept any other hints or tips regarding my use of C++. Thank you.

Comment: Look into forward declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two things,

> in FlightPlan and that would later accept an object pointer of a class derived from Aircraft? On compile I receive: error: ‘Aircraft’ does not name a type

Header must be included with the class Aircraft so it is declared before Flightplan. Or you can use forward declaration like this

```
class Aircraft;
```

Telling the compiler of the type Aircraft that it exists and the pointer can be declared you use in the class Flightplan.

Your problem is only about the existence of the type Aircraft. Use forward declaration or guarantee that the class is declared before you declare Flightplan.

P.S. don't forget about [virtual destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) in Aircaft class

Comment: Thanks for remembering that.

Comment: Your advice was well received, thank you. I already had the Aircraft.h in the FlightPlan.h but that wasn't doing it for me. The forward declaration did, and I have since used that to solve some other issues too. Thanks again.